# Making Windows XP installed in Virtual Box 6.0.4 detect a new hard disk after being installed

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, virtualbox

I installed Win XP 64 bits in Virtual Box 6.0.4 installed in Windows 10. Naively, I thought that if I connected a new hard disk I had a chance of this WindowsXP in Virtual Box could have detected it. What do I have to do for making Windows XP installed in Virtual Box 6.0.4 detect a new hard disk after being installed?

Answer (score 1):

First create new virtual hd. Then simply add new virtual hard drive.

Comment: No, actually he needs to create a new partition on the drive he already created.